# С# работа с bluetooth, протокол pbap

Tags: c#, bluetooth

Уже 4 дня тщетно пытаюсь вытащить контакты с андроид устройства, использую библиотеку 32feet: http://32feet.codeplex.com

Ошибка возникает на получении ответа, пишет

> operation failed

Мой код:

```
BluetoothClient bc = new BluetoothClient();

BluetoothDeviceInfo[] info = null;
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] paired = bc.DiscoverDevices(255, true, false, false, false);
info = bc.DiscoverDevices(999);

foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in info)
{

    if (device.DeviceName == "LG Spirit")// если это мое устройство
    {
        device.Refresh();
        device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.PhonebookAccess, true); // это ставил для теста - не помогло

        // Use pin "0000" for authentication
        BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, "0000"); // произвожу пайринг устройств


        var file = @"C:\Users\Serkser\Desktop\Работы на заказ\Работы на заказ\Test_bluetooth\test_bluetooth\test_bluetooth\bin\Debug\Новый точечный рисунок.jpg"; // это я пытался передать файл на телефон по простому obex - это работает на ура
        var uri = new Uri("obex-pbap://" + device.DeviceAddress); // обращаюсь по этому протоколу для получения адресной книги
        var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);

        request.Timeout = 300000;

        var response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // на этой строке на тлф приходит запрос на разрешение предоставления своей адресной книги, жму ДА, потом ждет весь таймаут и выдает эксепшн Operation Failed

        MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        // check response.StatusCode
        response.Close();
    }
}
```